# Randomize weighted array with weights lower than 1 and decimals

Tags: php, arrays, math, random

I have an array with weights on each value used to retrieve a random value based on those weights. I have used something like this in the past:

```
$items = array( "value1" => 30, "value2" => 70 );

$weighted = array();

foreach( $items as $value => $weight ) {
    $weighted = array_merge($weighted, array_fill(0, $weight, $value));
}

echo $result = $weighted[array_rand($weighted)];
```

But what if I need to use decimals on the weights? (The weights I use always sum up to 100 btw)

For example:

```
$items = array( "value1" => 0.5, "value2" => 99.5 );
```

So value1 would only be shown 0.5% of the times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could go like that:
First, create a decimal random number within your desired precision.
For example, create a random integer number between 0 and 10.000 and divide by 100 (in this case, it's precision is two digits after the comma). Let's name it random_value.

Then do it like that (in pseudo code):

```
    given: random_value, decimal in [0,100]
    sum = 0
    for each item in items
            sum += weight(item)
            if(sum >= random_value)
                    return item
                    (and break for-loop)
```

So if you got the weights (0.5, 45.5, 50) and random_value is 46,
we add 0.5 to the sum, get 0.5, thats not >= 46 -> go on
we add 45.5 to the sum, get 50, that is >= 46 -> second item it is

Comment: Is it necesarry to order the weights from lower to higher?